# fatal error: .h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic. I am trying to build my catkin ws but I got this error.

```
fatal error: ur5_demo_descartes/ur5_robot_model.h: No such file or directory
```

The exact path of file is

```
/home/ros-industrial/catkin_ws/src/ur5_demo_descartes/include/ur5_demo_descartes/ur5_robot_model.h
```

and I am using this in source file like this:

```
#include <ur5_demo_descartes/ur5_robot_model.h>
```

The package also added in the cMakeLists.txt and package.xml. Do you have any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365964/fatal-error:-.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [yemre0642](https://answers.ros.org/users/63525/yemre0642/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-19**:
please share your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml (without any comments) or provide a repository to reproduce

**Comment by [yemre0642](https://answers.ros.org/users/63525/yemre0642/) on 2020-11-19**:
Hi, you can check the repo from here: [https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/tree/melodic/exercises/Descartes_Planning_and_Execution/solution_ws/src]

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-19**:
Is this the repo that you cannot build? Which package shows the error? Some that you did? You need to be more specific if you expect us to help.

I'm not going to search through a repo with multiple packages or compile this on good luck.

Make sure to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add  `include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` in your `CMakelists.txt` file. Or take a look at the next ROS [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/237494/fatal-error-rosrosh-no-such-file-or-directory).

---

Originally posted by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) with karma: 52 on 2020-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yemre0642](https://answers.ros.org/users/63525/yemre0642/) on 2020-11-19**:
Thank you very much, it worked for me.